# How to use a single click handler instead of multiple for a task?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

The following link is a project I'm currently working on:
http://feathertest.me.pn/p-indoor.php#prod-stop

In the link provided above, I have list of clickable colors available on the right. Based on the color clicked by the user, the images on the left side change accordingly.

The following is the code snippet I used for that specific feature:

```
$(function() {
    $('#showdiv1').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div1').show();
    });
    $('#showdiv2').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
    });

    $('#showdiv3').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div3').show();
    });

    $('#showdiv4').click(function() {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
        $('#div4').show();
    });
})
```

**My HTML code snippet:**

```
<!-- mobile version start -->
            <div class="row hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-1">
                    <p class="prod-code">FB - 329</p>
                    <p class="prod-title">Monara</p>
                    <p class="prod-desc">The best in class from our range of Indoor Brooms. This is the only broom in the market that has five rows of syntetic bristles. A "Heavy Duty" broom suitable for high dust areas.</p>

                    <div class="prod-det">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Sweeps away more dirt at once while leaving no traces behind. </li>
                            <li>Split bristle edges for collecting fine dust.</li>
                            <li>Head enclosure constructed using the highest graded plastic material.</li>
                            <li>Uniform Italian handle thread.</li>
                            <li>Angled edges to reach corners.</li>
                            <li>150g of high quality synthetic bristles with excellent bend recovery for prolonged usage.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <div class="color-change"><b>Colours Available:</b></div>
                    <div class="color-box">
                        <a id="tmonara-showdiv1" class="cb-pp" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Purple"></a>
                        <a id="tmonara-showdiv2" class="cb-b" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Black"></a>
                        <a id="tmonara-showdiv3" class="cb-o" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Orange"></a>
                        <a id="tmonara-showdiv4" class="cb-p" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Pink"></a>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <p class="color-change"><i>(click to change colors of product)</i></p>
                </div> <!-- prod details end -->
            </div>
            <!-- mobile version end -->

            <div id="feather-prods" class="row">

                <div id="div1">
                <div id="monara-purple" class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-1">
                    <div class="prod-img"><img class="bigImg" src="images/broom/monara-pp-1.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom"></div>

                    <div class="thumbnailImg">
                      <div class="thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-pp-1.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div class="thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-pp-2.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div class="thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-pp-3.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div class="thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-pp-4.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div> <!-- prod 1 end -->

                <div id="div2" style="display:none;" >
                <div id="monara-green" class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-1">
                    <div class="prod-img"><img class="bigImg2" src="images/broom/monara-g-1.jpg" alt="feather, green monara broom"></div>

                    <div class="thumbnailImg">
                      <div class="thumb2"><img src="images/broom/monara-g-1.jpg" alt="feather, green monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div class="thumb2"><img src="images/broom/monara-g-2.jpg" alt="feather, green monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div class="thumb2"><img src="images/broom/monara-g-3.jpg" alt="feather, green monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div class="thumb2"><img src="images/broom/monara-g-4.jpg" alt="feather, green monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div> <!-- prod 2 end -->  

<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-1 hidden-xs">
                    <p class="prod-code">FB - 329</p>
                    <p class="prod-title">Monara</p>
                    <p class="prod-desc">The best in class from our range of Indoor Brooms. This is the only broom in the market that has five rows of syntetic bristles. A "Heavy Duty" broom suitable for high dust areas.</p>
                    
                    <br>
                    <div class="color-change"><b>Colours Available:</b></div>
                    <div class="color-box">
                        <a id="monara-showdiv1" class="cb-pp" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Purple"></a>
                        <a id="monara-showdiv2" class="cb-g" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Green"></a>
                        <a id="monara-showdiv3" class="cb-b" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Black"></a>
                        <a id="monara-showdiv4" class="cb-o" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Orange"></a>
                        <a id="monara-showdiv4" class="cb-p" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Pink"></a>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <p class="color-change"><i>(click to change colors of product)</i></p>

                    <div class="prod-det">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Sweeps away more dirt at once while leaving no traces behind. </li>
                            <li>Split bristle edges for collecting fine dust.</li>
                            <li>Head enclosure constructed using the highest graded plastic material.</li>
                            <li>Uniform Italian handle thread.</li>
                            <li>Angled edges to reach corners.</li>
                            <li>150g of high quality synthetic bristles with excellent bend recovery for prolonged usage.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- prod details end -->
</div>
```

**I have 2 questions:**

1. Is there a way to shorten the jQuery code? meaning, instead of using multiple click handlers, can I achieve the same task using just a single click handler? I'm a still a noob when it comes to jQuery.
2. If you notice I have a commented a section for the mobile view (I had to create a separate text block for the mobile view because I wanted a few changes in the design for the mobile viewport). I noticed, as soon as I created the mobile view section, the above jQuery stopped working for the desktop view and only worked for the mobile view, hence I had to recreate the same block of jQuery code with different ID values for the mobile view.

   How can I make the same jQuery code (mentioned above) work for both, mobile view and desktop view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so there are a ton of ways to approach this problem. This may or may not be the best way, but I think it's a simple approach. Instead of using IDs, you should use classes so that they can easily use the same click handler. Then, you can add a data attribute to the color choices to correspond to classes in the descriptions.
So this:

```
<a id="tmonara-showdiv1" class="cb-pp" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Purple"></a>
```

Would become this:

```
<a class="tmonara cb-pp" href="p-indoor.php#prod-stop" title="Purple" data-color="purple"></a>
```

And this:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Would become this:

```
<div id="div1" class="description purple"></div>
```

And then the jQuery code would look like this:

```
   $('.tmonara').click(function() {
        var colorClicked = $(this).data('color');
        $('.description').hide();
        $('.description.' + colorClicked).show();
    });
```

I created this JS Bin to show a working example. Please note: I deleted a lot of code just to simplify the example:
https://jsbin.com/johacetamo/edit?html,js,output

As for your second question, there can only be one instance of an ID on the page. Your mobile code is listed first, so the jQuery was finding the first instance of the ID and ignoring the second instance (your non-mobile view). This is why changing the IDs worked. If you use classes instead, you will not have this problem!

Hope that helps, please let me know if anything is still confusing or if I didn't answer your questions properly.

Comment: Voted up for a more complete answer than mine.

Comment: Thanks @VanquishedWombat :)

Comment: @HazraHameed I'm glad! :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach for the refactor of the click code is as follow, and it works on the principle that you can add classes to elements where the class is not to do with styling but is used as a group identifier :

1. Add a generic class to all the buttons, e.g. myButtonClass
2. Add a generic class to all the divs, e.g. myDiv
3. Modify your code such that the associated picture has a class matching the controlling button id. e.g.for button #showdiv1 give #div1 an additional class as class="#showdiv1".
4. Now modify your jquery as below:
   .

   ```
   $(".myButtonClass").on("click", function(e){

       // hide all the divs
       $(".myDiv").hide()  

       // show the div with class matching button element id attr
       $("." + $(this).prop("id")).show()    

   })
   ```

This jquery now covers all the buttons.